# How to add a column with indexing in UpdateRecord Nifi?

Tags: csv, apache-nifi

I m having some columns so I want to add a new column as id and want to give values to every row as 1,2,3,4....
for example I have this in a **`.csv`** file

| Name | City |
| --- | --- |
| John | Tokyo |
| Steve | Newyork |

the output I want :-

| ID | Name | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Tokyo |
| 2 | Steve | Newyork |

I am trying to use **UpdateRecord** processor for this, can anyone help me with?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `QueryRecord` processor:

- `Record Reader`: `CSVReader`
- `Record Writer`: `CSVRecordSetWriter`
- `row_num` (dynamic attribute):

```sql
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NAME, CITY ASC) AS ID, * FROM FLOWFILE
```

**input**

```
Name,City
John,Tokyo
Steve,Newyork
Tony,Bratislava
```

**output**

```
ID,Name,City
1,John,Tokyo
2,Steve,Newyork
3,Tony,Bratislava
```